# Issue using @Transactional in spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, cxf, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I'm mixing spring-data and CXF to create a RESTful endpoint that creates neo4j nodes. My structure is a set Interfaces which define the public facing methods, and my implementations which have several private methods under that are called by my public methods.

My private methods have spring-tx's `@Transactional` on them, and when I try to call these from my public methods, I get a `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException`. Below is a GitHub project that is setup to show my configuration and you can also run it to see what's wrong:

https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/broken-spring-neo4j-cxf.git

Can anyone help me? I've followed the steps from the documentation on spring-data-neo4j, but I cannot seem to get this working, can anyone help me?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question and mark this one as answered. The new question will get more viewers, being new, and it appears to be a different concern than the original question.

Comment: Done, reverted to original. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Transactional` annotation does not work on private methods.

From the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

You may be able to use the `aspectj` mode to enable this behavior on any type of method.

Comment: Do you have an example of `aspectj`, I've tried setting that as the `mode` to `aspectj` and tried other configuration options such as `proxy-target-class="true"` but seem unable to find a way to use it.

Comment: @Nicholas Sorry, I've not actually used it myself; just noticed in the doc that it seemed like an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighter on [chapter 11.5.6 of spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative):

> Method visibility and @Transactional
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.